# How to create unicode string from bytearray

Tags: java, android, unicode

I have to save some strings containing localized values to a byte array.

Then I have to reconstruct the strings from the byte array

I encode the string to byte array like this:

```
        byte addr = 0x08;
        for (String s : values) {
            char[] dataBytes = s.toCharArray();
            int length = s.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    if(i * 4 + j < length ) {
                        buffer[j] = (byte) Character.codePointAt(dataBytes, i * 4 + j);
                    } else {
                        buffer[j] = (byte) 0;
                    }
                }
                nfcHandler.write(buffer, addr);
                addr++;
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

How do I reconstruct the string? I've tried

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and

```
bytes.toString();
```

but neither works.

Any idea how to acomplish this?

Please help..!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you encode the bytes yourself? Can't you use s.getBytes(Charset charset to do the encoding? Using s.getBytes(Charset charset) and afterwards new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset) should give the same String.

Comment: To be honest it's cargo cultism at the moment. I'm still learning android programming. I'll try this approach :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are decoding a byte array to a `String` is fine, but you are doing way too much work on the encoding side. Use the `String.getBytes()` method instead:

```java
byte[] buffer = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// use buffer at needed...
```